# Function and Code are not passing through variables properly. Somewhat of a debugging request in a twitter-like system code

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

For some reason the form data is not being passed through properly in a function that I have used from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-twitter-interface/index.html#author1

I am not sure if I am using implode correctly. If you notice though, I did change some values in the tutorial because I just felt that they seemed incorrect. Just go ahead and let me know what I should change. Right now, profile.php comes up and no posts show up. However, the databases are getting all of the posts perfectly.

**There are no error messages... Something just isn't being passed through properly.**

I am at the last part of the tutorial.
My Code that is on index\profile.php:

```
    <!-- Shows posts on page-->
<?php
$posts = show_posts($_SESSION['userid']);

if (count($posts)){
?>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='500'>
<?php
foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
    echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
    echo "<td>".$list['user_id'] ."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n";
    echo "<small>".$list['stamp'] ."</small></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
?>
<p><b>You haven't posted anything yet!</b></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is the code in functions.php:

```
function show_posts($userid,$limit=0){
$posts = array();
$user_string ="'" .implode("','", $posts). "'";
$extra =  " and id in ($user_string)";

if ($limit > 0){
    $extra = "limit $limit";
}else{
    $extra = '';    
}

$sql = "select user_id, body, stamp from posts 
    where user_id='$user_string'
    order by stamp desc $extra";
//echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $posts[] = array(   'stamp' => $data->stamp, 
                        'user_id' => $data->user_id, 
                        'body' => $data->body
                );
}
return $posts;
```

}

Comment: "Not working" is definitely NOT acceptable description. This topic should be closed as not a real question.

Comment: Please add a more specific question.  What result do you get?  Are there error messages?  What does and doesn't happen?

Comment: IBM developers article with sql injection. as usual

Answer (score 1):

One obvious error I saw:

```
function show_posts($userid,$limit=0){
$posts = array();
$user_string ="'" .implode("','", $posts). "'";
```

$posts is defined just before you implode it, so it will always be empty. Did you change that line? Shouldn't it be:

```
implode("','", $userid);
```

??

But honestly. This is more of a "request to debug my code" than an actual question.

Comment: Ugh, I just noticed that mistake. Thank you amorhs, hopefully it will help in the future. You are also right about me asking to debug the code... I'm sorry if that was not allowed in here.

Comment: It's fine by me. It's just the general attitude of most users that they don't like these types of questions.

Comment: Not "debug my code" but "Foresee from that mess what I want and write code for me". It is definitely "too localized" kind of question. It will never help anyone else. It's rather request for charity

Comment: i'm sorry about that Shrapnel. I just tried deleting it but it already has answers. Obviously I'm new here, should have read the rules. My apologies again

Comment: Truong, you need some community or a coding pal that can help you look at bugs or problems.. I used IRC a lot back in the day when I started ..

Comment: @Truong nobody asking you to delete. You should keep your question, but rather **ask it properly.** First of all you have to tell in words **what you actually want** from this code. And what you get. Actually. Don't you understand that it's impossible to tell it just by watching your code?

Answer (score 1):

Final created **mysql query is wrong at all.**

```
echo $sql;
```

and you will see how the query is wrong you are adding condition part after order by which should be with the where clause.

and `$user_string` is blank at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra set of single quotes in your implode, should'nt it be...

```
$user_string ="'" .implode(",", $posts). "'";
```